# Recurrance Relation - T(n)

Tags: recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to solve this recurrance relation problem yet I cant seem to find an upper bound.

$$
T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{3})+nlog^2(n)
$$

using the tree method I've got to $O(nlog^2(n))$, using the recursion calculation method, I've got $O(nlog^3(n)$

In either methods I'm not 100% certain of the steps I did, so to my assumption both my answers are wrong.

Any help would do alot.

Thanks!

Comment: As a first step, ignore the $\,n\log^2(n)\,$ term and see what you get.

Comment: @Somos $T(n)=2^kT(\frac{n}{3^k})$ where $k=log{n}$ in base $3$. from that I get that the upper bound is $O(n)$. thus resulting in $n+nlog^2(n)$ which is bound by $O(nlog^2(n))$, that is how I got the one of the solutions I've described in the post.

Comment: I would go with the second method since it implies the first.

Comment: I don't seem to completely understand your explanation, care to elaborate?

Comment: The $\,O(n\log^3(n))\,$ upper bounds $\,O(n\log^2(n))\,$ so it is safe to use it.

Comment: @Somos I agree and see that, yet I'm asked to find a tight upper bound to the recursive formula In the post. therefor I'm not sure should it be $O(nlog^2(n))$ or would the tight upper bound be $O(nlog^3(n))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking $n = 3^m$ and considering $\log\equiv\log_3$ we have

$$
T(3^m)=2T(3^{m-1})+3^m m^2
$$

calling now $\mathcal{T}(\cdot)=T(3^{(\cdot)})$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}(m)=2\mathcal{T}(m-1)+3^m m^2
$$

The homogeneous has the solution $\mathcal{T}_h(m)=2^m c_0$ and making now $\mathcal{T}_p(m)=2^m c_0(m)$ after substitution into

$$
\mathcal{T}_p(m)=2\mathcal{T}_p(m-1)+3^m m^2
$$

we obtain the recurrence

$$
c_0(m) = c_0(m-1) + m^2\left(\frac 32\right)^m
$$

with solution

$$
c_0(m) = \left(\frac 32\right)^m\left(3m^2-12m+30\right)-30
$$

then

$$
\mathcal{T}(m) = \left(c_0+\left(\frac 32\right)^m\left(3m^2-12m+30\right)-30\right)2^m
$$

going now backwards with $m = \log_3 n$ we obtain

$$
T(n) = 30n+3n(\log_3 n)^2-12n\log_3 n -30\cdot 2^{\log_3 n}
$$

hence

$$
T(n) = \mathcal{O}\left(n(\log_3 n)^2\right)
$$